# join on same table ignoring null values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
id userid    game   date_t       hdigit   inside  outside
1  user101    xy     02-09-2017    1       10
2  user101    xy     02-09-2017    1               40
3  user101    xx     02-09-2017    2       40
4  user101    xx     02-09-2017    3               90
```

I want display data like

```
id userid    game   date_t     hdigit inside outside
1  user101    xy    02-09-2017  1       10     40
3  user101    xx    02-09-2017  2       40
4  user101    xx    02-09-2017  3              90
```

I have tried this

```
SELECT h.userid,h.game,h.date_t,h.hdigit,h.inside,htwo.outside 
 FROM `hadap_game` AS h JOIN hadap_game AS htwo WHERE h.userid=:user
 AND htwo.userid=:uer AND h.hdigit=htwo.hdigit AND h.game=htwo.game 
 AND h.inside IS NOT NULL AND htwo.outside IS NOT NULL
```

it is printing the above thing but I want to print the row which have null values too

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could probably do this simply using `GROUP BY`?

```
SELECT 
    h.userid,
    h.game,
    h.date_t,
    h.hdigit,
    MAX(IFNULL(h.inside, htwo.inside)) AS inside,
    MAX(IFNULL(h.outside, htwo.outside)) AS outside
 FROM 
    hadap_game AS h 
    LEFT JOIN hadap_game AS htwo ON htwo.userid = h.userid AND htwo.hdigit = h.hdigit AND htwo.game = h.game AND htwo.id <> h.id
WHERE 
    h.userid = :user
GROUP BY
    h.userid,
    h.game,
    h.date_t,
    h.hdigit;
```

This does a few other things that you might not need/ want, but it's basically the same as your original query, other than it works when there aren't two rows per unique reference.

Comment: it should be IFNULL

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer to suit, or `COALESCE` would also work I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there will only ever be 1 or 2 rows (so not 3 or more matching rows):-

```
SELECT h.userid,
h.game,
h.date_t,
h.hdigit,
COALESCE(h.inside,h2.inside) AS inside,
COALESCE(h.outside,h2.outside) AS outside
FROM `hadap_game` AS h 
LEFT OUTER JOIN hadap_game AS h2 
ON h.hdigit=h2.hdigit 
AND h.game=h2.game 
WHERE h.userid=:user
AND h2.userid=:uer 
UNION
SELECT h2.userid,
h2.game,
h2.date_t,
h2.hdigit,
COALESCE(h.inside,h2.inside) AS inside,
COALESCE(h.outside,h2.outside) AS outside
FROM `hadap_game` AS h2
LEFT OUTER JOIN hadap_game AS h 
ON h.hdigit=h2.hdigit 
AND h.game=h2.game 
WHERE h.userid=:user2
AND h2.userid=:uer2
```